# the method 'setData' isn't defined for the type 'documentreference'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently in the middle of migrating all of my out of date code to the newest version of firebase and when I updated the firebase dependency it gave me the error that the method 'setData' isn't defined for the type 'documentreference'.

```
class DatabaseService {

  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({ this.uid });

  // Collection reference
  // final CollectionReference brewCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('brews');
  final CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> brewCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('brews');



  Future updateUserData(String sugars, String name, int strength) async {
    return await brewCollection.doc(uid).setData({
      'sugars' : sugars,
      'name'  : name,
      'strength' : strength
    });
  }


  // Brew list from snapshot
  List<Brew> _brewListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
      return Brew(
          name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
          strength: doc.data['strength'] ?? 0,
          sugars: doc.data['sugars'] ?? '0'
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  // Get brews stream
  Stream<List<Brew>> get brews {
    return brewCollection.snapshots().map(_brewListFromSnapshot);
  }

  UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserData(
        uid: uid,
        name: snapshot.data['name'],
        sugars: snapshot.data['sugars'],
        strength: snapshot.data['strength']
    );
  }

  // Get user document
  Stream<UserData> get userData {
    return brewCollection.doc(uid).snapshots().map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `setData()` method was renamed to just `set()` in version 2.0 of the FlutterFire plugins.

For cases such as this, I find it most helpful to keep the reference documentation handy, such as for the [`DocumentReference` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) in this specific case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I took a look at the documentation and it helped a ton! I am just having an issue with the string and integer values I am assigning to 'Brew'. Specifically the values inside of the data method. It is now saying that the object '[]' is not defined for the type object function. I am sure it is just a syntax error that I am not picking up on that comes with the new firebase update but I am not too sure. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You might want to search for that new error message, as I've seen it pop up **a lot** in the past few months and the fix is always very similar.

Comment: Thanks for the input I found this thread that answered the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68615606/the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-type-object-function-try-defining